Is God glad when punishing us?
Devarim 28:63 reads:

וְהָיָה כַּאֲשֶׁר שָׂשׂ י״י עֲלֵיכֶם לְהֵיטִיב אֶתְכֶם וּלְהַרְבּוֹת אֶתְכֶם כֵּן יָשִׂישׂ י״י עֲלֵיכֶם לְהַאֲבִיד אֶתְכֶם וּלְהַשְׁמִיד אֶתְכֶם וְנִסַּחְתֶּם מֵעַל הָאֲדָמָה אֲשֶׁר אַתָּה בָא שָׁמָּה לְרִשְׁתָּהּ.
It shall happen that as Hashem rejoiced over you to do you good, and to multiply you, so Hashem will rejoice over you to cause you to perish and to destroy you; and you shall be plucked from upon the land where you go in to possess it.

Although Chazal (b Megillah 10a) say that it means God will cause others to rejoice when destroying you (your enemies), Onkelos renders it straightforwardly, as translated above.
Despite Yashar (R. Yitzchak Shemuel Reggio) ad loc explaining that as God loves us He therefore rectifies our behavior via punishment, the plain language of the pasuk indicates that HaShem is as happy to punish us as He is to reward us.
It sounds disturbing (as were Chazal in the referenced gemara) that HaShem should actually enjoy administering the therapy that we humans experience as pain and suffering.

There are a lot of terrifying statements like this...

Is not the point of that Chazal in Megillah to answer your question. He's glad to do it because it helps us, but he isn't really, כביכול.

וְיָדַעְתָּ֖ עִם־לְבָבֶ֑ךָ כִּ֗י כַּאֲשֶׁ֨ר יְיַסֵּ֥ר אִישׁ֙ אֶת־בְּנ֔וֹ יְהוָ֥ה אֱלֹהֶ֖יךָ מְיַסְּרֶֽךָּ

@DoubleAA combine with hilchot deot 2:3 ואם רצה להטיל אימה על בניו ובני ביתו או על הצבור אם היה פרנס ורצה לכעס עליהן כדי שיחזרו למוטב יראה עצמו בפניהם שהוא כועס כדי ליסרם ותהיה דעתו מישבת בינו לבין עצמו כאדם שהוא מדמה כועס בשעת כעסו והוא אינו כועס.

It sounds to me that Hashem always rejoices over us because of his love for us regardless of this being a time of giving reward or giving punishment rather than Hashem rejoicing in punishing us

A statement like this one can be understood at a level mida keneged mida. In other words a person or community were seeking gladness at provoking Hashem. The punishment, k'viyakhol inevitably should reflect k'neged mida a similar response. The punished people should feel as if Hashem is happy. Similarly, many people are glad at performing mitzvos properly, k'neged mida Hashem is glad giving the reward. In other words, joy at doing a mitzvah makes a person feel as if Hashem is glad at rewarding a person. However, as we understand, G-d is not having the emotion, He only applies righteous justice.
