A question on rejoicing in the downfall of enemies
Sanhedrin 39b says:

At that time the ministering angels desired to recite a song before God.  God said to them: My handiwork [the Egyptians] are drowning in the sea, and you sing a song before Me?  Rabbi Yosei bar Ḥanina says: God does not rejoice in their downfall, but He causes others to rejoice.

Why does God "cause" (note: not "allow") people to rejoice at the downfall of their enemies, but refrains from rejoicing Himself?  If the lesson is that we can rejoice in our victory but not in the pain inflicted on the enemy, why wouldn't that apply to God as well?

Doesn’t the Gemara itself say that the reason why he does not rejoice himself is because they are is handiwork? That is something that can only apply to Him, since there is no other creator.

I took Rabbi Hanina's statement to be general, not applicable only to this case.  Also, why "cause"?  Why not let the people rejoice of their free will?

Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/145044/is-god-glad-when-punishing-us and the answer is exactly the same.

1). Rashi states there "שנאכם" That the others are the "enemies" who rejoice.
Presumably this means that you can praise Hashem over being saved, like the Jews at the splitting of the sea.
2).  ויאמר שמואל (Sanhedrin 39b) similarly: The angels praise Hashem over his might and this is inappropriate because it is like praising "vengance". But the Jews are praising Hashem over the salvation.
Now it makes sense why Hashem nor the Angels would "sing" or "enjoy" since they are not "saved" via this act of strength.
3). Chid''a (Rosh David, Parsha Beshalach 54) says, that the angels cannot rejoice at the moment of punishment, but after the נגמר הדין (literally: end of judgement) the punishment is over and the miracle is revealed it is appropriate to sing Shira even for the angels and presumably this might apply to Hashem as well?
